# Passing parameters to Index action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I need to create a child view that will allow the user to insert related data after selecting a row on the main gridview.

The child view must receive an ID that will indicate which is the parent row.

How can I pass this parameter? ViewBag?

PS: The views and controllers are different and the child view is opened using a Html.ActionLink to the Index action of another controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the ID of the parent as a parameter to your action method which invokes the child view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Related Data","Add",new { @id=364})
```

*Replace 364 with the dynamic value from your view*

And in your Child Action,Get the Parent object from the ID and show that in child view. Assuming you have a ViewModel liket his for your child view.

```
public class ChildDetails
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Note { set;get;}
  public int ParentID { set;get;}
  public string ParentName { set;get;}
}
```

Get the Parent details and set the relevant property values in your ViewModel for child view.

```
public ActionResult Add(int id)
{
  var parent=yourRepositary.Get(id);
  ChildDetails childViewModel=new ChildDetails();
  childViewModel.ParentID=id;
  childViewModel.Name=parent.Name;
  return View(childViewModel);
}
```

Your Child view will be strongly binded to `ChildDetails` class

```
@model ChildDetails

<h2>@Model.ParentName</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Note)
  @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ParentId)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: I'd like to use the existing Index action to list the child items, instead of creating a new action. Is it possible?

Comment: you can use an existing action. i wrote add method to make it a generic example

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a query string, since you are opening a different action.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters in several ways.

```
ViewBag.MyParam = "1";

ViewData("MyParam") = "1";

TempData("MyParam") = "1";
```

Note:  This is VB, so C# will be a little different.

Otherwise, you can pass via the querystring as stated by Rob.